# Pyspark UDF when applied on more than 1000 columns fails in spark 1.6.2

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a pyspark lookup UDF which basically converts True to 1 and False to 0.
Following is my code:

```
binary_dict = {"True": 1, "False": 0 }

broadcastVar = sc.broadcast(binary_dict) 

def lookup(x):
  if broadcastVar.value.get(x) is None:
    return x
  else:
    return broadcastVar.value.get(x)

mycolumnList = 920 columns
Df.columns = 944 columns

dF1 = dF.select(*(lookup_udf(col(c)).alias(c) if c in mycolumnList else c for c in Df.columns))
dF1.take(100)

Error:
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot evaluate expression:
PythonUDF#lookup(input[111, StringType])
```

This is what i have tried so far:
(1) When i just 100 columns in mycolumnList, i don't see this exception happening.
(2) When number of columns in mycolumnList is more than 100 i see the python UDF exception.

Please let me know how to solve this issue.

Comment: You don't need a udf function for the requirement you have. It can be done using [when](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#when-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-java.lang.Object-) inbuilt function.

Comment: Where do you define the `UDF`, which type is it expecting? I don't think the problem comes from the number of columns but rather from an input or output of the wrong type

Comment: This is my UDF lookup_udf = udf(lookup).  When i modified my code to mintDf_final = mintDf_final.select([when(col(c) == "True", 1).when(col(c) == "False", 0).alias(c) if c in mintDf_binary_cols else c for c in mintDf_final.columns]), i don't see any issues even when the columns are around 1000. I am not sure what is the difference between using the UDF vs this code.